# Galaxy S20FE not charging when >40 C

Tags: samsung, charging

My phone updated yesterday and now it charges only up to 60% and then stops when temperature reaches 42C (it still shows "charging" label but without remaining time). If I manage to drop its temperature below 40C, it continues charging. Does anyone else experience this? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: That is as far as I know a common behavior of mobile devices. lithium batteries wear out  with an increased rate if the temperature is getting too high. High end phones like yours have a very fast and power consuming CPU which creates additional heat and the temperature charge protection exist to prevent "self destruction". If you charge your device, place it in a cool environment and don't use it and/or point  a fan on it.

Comment: It was lying plugged in for hours and only got to 63%. My environment temperature is 21 C. How is it normal behavior?

Comment: Is it possible that you have accidentally installed an app that misuses your phone when it is charging? That would explain the high temperature. Alternatively it could also be a hardware defect like a bad temperature sensor, therefore it would be interesting if the phone feels hotter than usual.

Comment: You can look up the battery usage. Find out whats draining it so fast

Comment: To rule out app misbehaving try charging in safe mode